# Breaking lines/linebreaks in chemformula names

Tags: line-breaking, chemformula

In the process of writing an inorganic nomenclature lecture, I would like to put centered multi-line text in the name function of chemformula.

As far as I've tried, creating a new line with `\\` does not work. Using `\newline` gives a multiline output, but shifted to the left. Escaping the multiline text did not work better.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

\ch{!(hydrogen~chloride\newline{}chlorhydric~acid)( HCl )} % gives left-shifted output

\ch{!(hydrogen~chloride\\chlorhydric~acid)( HCl )} % does not typeset

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chemformula` allows you to set the “name” any way you want. This also allows you to put it inside a table. (The only downside is that you can't use `\\` for a new line here, because `\ch` bypasses `\\` in its input in order to allow usage over multiple lines in environments like `align`¹.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newcommand\myformat[1]{%
  \scriptsize\centering
  \def\newline{\tabularnewline}%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    #1
  \end{tabular}%
}

\setchemformula{name-format=\myformat}

\begin{document}

\ch{!( hydrogen~chloride \newline chlorhydric~acid )( HCl )}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

1. This in turn allows the `chemmacros` package to define the `reactions` environment.

Comment: Thanks cgnieder ! This solutions gives imho a more intuitive input text, I'll add that to my bag of tricks.
Re-reading your code, I can see it will allow me to be much more efficient in my use of the naming of chemicals...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch{!( \chname(chlorhydric~acid)(hydrogen~chloride) )( HCl )}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @polyn. Was not aware of this possibility of ```chemformula```.